# Threshold level check

Tags: matlab, simulink

How can I generate a simulink model to tell me if a certain output x signal has reached a threshold level after n seconds during the system run time? I would like to consider the last value of x and if so, enable an alarm value of -1.

Comment: For example, we can imagine that the system should check every 10 seconds if the last signal value x is above a certain threshold y established earlier. Once this has been done, it will take place every 10 seconds until the simulation is over. If, for example, I have exceeded the limit by 8 times in 100 seconds of simulation (then 10 tests) then it signals an alarm.

Comment: There is a comparison block. "Bigger than"

Comment: do you want to check something similar to x(n)>threshold ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do the following comparison:
x(n) >= threshold
In Simulink there is a block called "weighted sample time" that you can use to know the sample time. Then you can use a comparator to check if sample time is equal to n and another comparator to make sure x is greater than n

[image: simulink model]

Comment: For example, we imagine having a periodic reference signal that changes every 2 seconds (it would be my violet signal). The total simulation time is 10 seconds. If y = 1 is my threshold (drawn in yellow) I would like to have a counter that tells me that the purple signal has exceeded the limit by 5 times in total.    ![Valid XHTML](http://imgur.com/a/gERdJ). @M.Khd

Comment: In the comment there is the picture I am referring to. [Valid XHTML](http://imgur.com/a/gERdJ).

Comment: @Ander I invite you to see the link Valid XHTML in the previous comment. ty

Comment: My goal would be to use elementary simulink blocks to make it compatible with other software platforms such as targetlink